# How to change background color in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

```
require(ggvis)
require(dplyr)
map_data = ggplot2::map_data("world")
map_data %>% select(long, lat, group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  ggvis(x = ~long, y = ~lat) %>% layer_paths(fill:="#666666") %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y")
```

That produces a nice map, but I'd like control over the "ocean" color (e.g. "black"). How to do that?

More generally, the ocean color is the plot default background.

Comment: By "background" you mean the ocean part of the map right?

Comment: Please edit your question to spell `dplyr` correctly.

Comment: Do you have to use `ggvis`, e.g. is it a requirement that the map be interactive?

Comment: @jlhoward - strictly speaking, no. I already have the end-state via ggplot2, but I'm trying to determine how to do this in ggvis. 

I actually have another "blocker" in ggvis that I don't even know how to ask a question about.

Comment: You might get more interest if you showed your ggplot solution and what it produces, as an example of what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a layer_rects seems to have done it:

```
require(ggvis)
require(dplyr)
map_data = ggplot2::map_data("world")
minx = min(map_data$long -1)
maxx = max(map_data$long +1)
miny = min(map_data$lat - 1)
maxy = max(map_data$lat + 1)
map_data %>% select(long, lat, group) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  ggvis(x = ~long, y = ~lat) %>% 
  layer_rects(x=minx, x2=maxx, y=maxy, y2=miny, fill:="#000000") %>%
  layer_paths(fill:="#666666") %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% hide_axis("y")
```

[image]